# Does Flutter in Android Studio work better in Linux?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'd like to know if they have information about whether the Android emulator, and Android Studio, work better and faster on Linux.

In which Linux distribution do you advise me to install the SDK?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion... It works fine in Windows or Mac, so why are you asking specifcally about Linux? You're welcome to try it for yourself

Comment: I would suggest that you try it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using flutter on linux and I'd say that it is much faster than running it on anyother platform, you can even compare the app gradle build between mac, win and linux the results will be amazing on linux.  I'm using it on ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't matter on what linux distribution you run the performance is gonna be the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question has popped up for a 'Late Answers' review as the question is over 2 years old.  If you could add some performance metrics to give your answer more credibility it would be useful and you avoid being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is a matter of opinion. However, Google mostly uses [Debian](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-moves-to-debian-for-in-house-linux-desktop/) in house, so if you want an "official" recommendation go with that.

Flutter should run fine in every distro, though.

Comment: Thank you to all folks,
I will do the exercise and I will measure the compilation times of the same app in Windows and in Ubuntu. I will write the results.
Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: @DomDunk|
how that going with you? which is better to use?